# How to say "nothing in particular" in this context?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> What Job would you like to have 10 years from now?
>
> I hope to be my own boss and have my own business because I am too old
>   to be an employee.
>
> What kind of business you want to have?
>
> **Nothing in my mind now**..I don't have a specific plan...it is just a dream.

**I'm not sure whether I used "nothing in my mind" correctly, and I mean that I don't know what I will do.  What can I say instead?**

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying *[I can think of] nothing in particular*, just as you have it in the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Nothing in my mind” works well, although it would be idiomatic to omit the “my”:

> Nothing in mind.

You might also consider (if applicable/true):

> I haven’t decided yet.
>
> I haven’t really thought about it (yet).